# Made a mess of the tree, how to go back w/o merge?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I accidentally committed several files scattered around multiple directories.  The good news is nobody else has committed anything to the repository yet.  The bad news is my clumsy attempts to revert the files have been digging me in an ever-deepening hole.

I'd right-click the file in Windows Explorer, do TortoiseSVN -> Show Log, select the old, good version, right-click, and experiment with Save revision to..., Revert to this revision, and Revert changes from this revision.  Either the revert merges in crap I don't want, or it seems to work and I commit but the commit doesn't match the right revisiony, or the commit complains the file's in conflict and makes me merge to commit, and then my manual merge is rejected.

If I had been smart I would have come here first for advice, because I've found nice clean instructions on how to revert, but my hacking around seems to have thwarted the system.

The proper way appears to have been to go to the top of the tree, show log, select the checkin that started my problems, and "Revert changes from this Revision".  When I try that now, though, the guru meditates a while and then tells me it can't merge in changes from the future.

I don't really want to merge anything, I want to take an axe and chop off the crap.

How can I go back in time now?

Comment: did you try to do fresh checkout in a fresh local folder and try your revert to this revision there?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing.  Fresh folder on a clean machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem was that my working copy had files that were out of sync with the svn tree.  I cleaned them up by:
  a1) finding which files were out of sync with the svn tree
  a2) deleting them,
  a3) doing an update to replace them.

After that cleanup, things worked as they should.  I tried the revert procedure again: 
  b1) from top of the tree opened the Show Logs window,
  b2) selected the first bad check-in, and 
  b3) from right-click context-menu chose Revert changes from this revision.

It went perfectly that time - I carefully verified it.  I diffed each file with the good revision and got binary equal results each time.

c1) I committed the reverted files.

Then I went back to Show Logs, selected the good version and the top version, compared files, and got binary equals again.

It's all good now.  Thanks all for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the last correct revision before you made the mess was 1234, and you're now at revison 1240. Follow this procedure:

- Make sure your working copy is updated to the last revision, and doesn't contain any local modification (use *Check for modifications* in the TortoiseSVN menu)
- Click "Show log" on the root folder of your working copy
- Find the revision 1234. Right-click on it, and choose "Revert to this revision" (and not "Revert changes from this revision"). This will undo all the commits, from 1240 to 1235, that you made since revision 1234 and make your working copy be like it was at revision 1234.
- Commit, with the message "Revert all the mess I have introduced since revision 1234".